# Font awesom icons alignment

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I try to place three fa icons in line so that they have equal height. The thing is that they do not look aligned even if I set their sizes manually (via font-size property) (I need them to be around 11px though)  . I've been trying to change their positions as well for quite a lot of time. And what is the result:

```css
.trash {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 11px;
}
.upload {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 11px;
}
.download {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
  font-size: 11px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <i class="fa fa-download download"></i>
<i class="fa fa-upload upload"></i>
<i class="fa fa-trash trash"></i>
```

Obviously, they are not aligned. Is it possible to make them more "even"? I know that similar questions have already been asked, but they did't really help me.

Comment: I think your icons are aligned after you set the top:1px download. I set a line for  [ https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/bu0ufmse/2/ ]

Comment: I'm afraid the offset is in the caracter itself. You have to specifically target each caracter that is not designed with the same height than others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As all caracters don't have the same baseline, you have to play with each individually. The red borders in my example show it. This is the best I can do, I set the `font-size` to 30px in order to check alignement.

```css
.icons {
    font-size: 30px;
  }

.fa {
  border-top: 1px red solid;
  border-bottom: 1px red solid;
}

.download {
  position: relative;
  top: 0.07em;
}
.download:before {
   font-size: 1.06em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="icons">
  <i class="fa fa-download fa-4x download"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-upload fa-4x upload"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-trash fa-4x trash"></i>
</div>
```

Use relative font sizes (`em` unit) for adjustments, and it will be the same whatever the font-size is.

Comment: Kudos for pointing out the baseline issue, not all icons are created the same!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to give them all a fixed-width and central text alignment:

```css
.fa {
  text-align: center;
  width: 16px;
}
```

Naturally you'll need to play around with the width to get it to look the way you want with your desired font size.

[Modified JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tgt5Lnom/1/).

Before:

[image: Before]

After:

[image: After]

Comment: @AlFoиceѫ the icons are the same height in OP's example. http://i.imgur.com/iua2FCf.png

Comment: Each of the font caracter don't have the same height and the same basemine as the others. Zoom your example (or increase the font size), it will be obvious. Have a look at my answer and you may understand...

Comment: @AlFoиceѫ must be browser specific. No matter how far I zoom in Chrome they're all the same height with the same baseline. The red lines in the image I shared above demonstrate this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```css
ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin: 0 11px;
}
i {
  padding-top: 20%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<ul>
  <li><i class="fa fa-download"></i>
  </li>
  <li><i class="fa fa-upload"></i>
  </li>
  <li><i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Just add ` fa-4x` class to icons and you will see that you don't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

on a class for the icons?